OpenApi - oneOf - types are string not object
I have an openapi spec where one of the objects can contain only one of 2 ids: type1 id or type2 id. Each of these ids is just of type string. The official docs show the use of refs when using oneOf, which would suggest that they need to be an object but in my case the 2 types are just of type string.
"domainId": {
         "oneOf":
            [
             {
                "$ref": "#/components/type1Id"
             },
             {
                "$ref": "#/components/type2Id"
             }
            ]
          },
"components":
    {
        "type1Id":
        {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "type2Id":
        {
            "type": "string"
        }
}

Is this the best way of defining it?

Is there any technical difference between the type1Id and type2Id string types? Like min/max length, regex pattern, etc. oneOf won't work if both subschemas are of the same type without any unique attributes that would make it possible to distinguish between those types.

no, they are both of type GUID


they are both of type GUID

oneOf requires that the subschemas have unique attributes that make it possible to distinguish between the subschemas - such as different types, different regex patterns, etc. So that the server or client can unambiguously match a data instance to a specific subschema.
If both subschemas are just type: string without any distinguishing characteristics, oneOf won't work. Instead, use:
"domainId": {
  "type": "string"
},



I suppose if the client had sent the following I was hoping if spec could handle it, then I could deduce that it is of type1Id and now go do something different than if I had received type2Id:
"domainId": { "type1Id": "410979c4-e194-43a0-a5d2-2e6fe063094e" },


In this case domainId is an object rather than a string, and you can use oneOf as follows. Note how the type1IdSchema and type2IdSchema schemas are defined.
"domainId": {
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/type1IdSchema"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/type2IdSchema"
    }
  ]
},

...

"components": {
  "schemas": {

    "type1IdSchema": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "type1Id"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "type1Id": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },

    "type2IdSchema": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "type2Id"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "type2Id": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}


thanks for the explanation on the unique attributes. I still need some way to distinguish if it is type1Id or type2Id, I don't think that answer gives that.

How will your code implementation determine if "410979c4-e194-43a0-a5d2-2e6fe063094e" is type1Id or type2Id?

I suppose if the client had sent the following I was hoping if spec could handle it, then I could deduce that it is of type1Id and now go do something different than if I had received type2Id : "domainId": {
"type1Id": "410979c4-e194-43a0-a5d2-2e6fe063094e"
},
